# Most unfavourable question

Tags: discussion

What's the most unfavourable question ever asked? When I ask this, I mean the one with the most downvotes.

The answer can either be the the whole of Stack Exchange or just a Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 218 downvotes on SO:

[How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)

To answer your question (and other trivia like it): fork [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/216314/most-downvoted-question).

Comment: What does forking a query do?

Comment: @user12321 It creates your version of the query, which you can edit to fit your purpose.  Questions about Data Explorer can be asked on this site (not in comments), tagged  with data-explorer. Although it's better to experiment with the site first, and read some online SQL tutorial.